# Is it correct to use past simple in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses

This is the first time that I **watched** this film

Can I use another forms here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you are speaking about the present moment you would need to say 'This is the first time I have watched this film'.

However if you saw it a week ago, you could say 'Last Thursday was the first time I watched the film'. Or you could use the pluperfect ' Last Thursday... that I had watched the film'.